# Specific Targeting of Hosts Based on File Name

Tags: networking, ansible, yaml, juniper, junos-automation

I am using ansible to send configuration ".set" files to a Junos OS devices using the "junos_install_config" module. I want to send specific files to specific hosts based on the names.

eg. I want to send the file "vMX1.set" to host vMX1, file "vMX2.set" to host vMX2 ect.

At the moment I am doing it like this:

```
---
name: Configure Junos Devices
hosts: all
roles:
    - Juniper.junos
connection: local
gather_facts: no
tasks:
   - name: Send to Device 1
     when: ansible_hostname == vMX1
     junos_install_config:
         host={{ inventory_hostname }}
         file=/home/usr/resources/vMX1.set
         overwrite=false
- name: Send to Device 2
     when: ansible_hostname == vMX2
     junos_install_config:
         host={{ inventory_hostname }}
         file=/home/usr/resources/vMX2.set
         overwrite=false
```

This works however is very time consuming and not very logical. If for example I have 50 config files and 50 devices, I would have to write 50 different tasks. Is there any way to automate this so that the playbook checks the name of the task and assigns the file with the corresponding name?

The host file looks like this

```
[vMXrouters]
vMX1 ansible_ssh_host=10.249.89.22
vMX2 ansible_ssh_host=10.249.89.190
```

Comment: How does the inventory look like? Where does the *ansible_hostname* come from?

Comment: The host file looks as follows for 2 devices

[vMXrouters]
vMX1 ansible_ssh_host=10.249.89.22
vMX2 ansible_ssh_host=10.249.89.190

however I would like to be able to add more devices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"Is there any way to automate this so that the playbook checks the name of the task and assigns the file with the corresponding name?*"

A: The playbook below should do the job

```
- name: Configure Junos Devices
  hosts: all
  vars:
    list_of_devices: ['vMX1', 'vMX2']
  tasks:
    - name: "Send to {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      junos_install_config:
        host="{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        file="/home/usr/resources/{{ inventory_hostname }}.set"
        overwrite=false
      when: inventory_hostname in list_of_devices
      delegate_to: localhost
```

The playbook is simpler if the group of the hosts is defined

```
- name: Configure Junos Devices
  hosts: vMX_devices
  tasks:
    - name: "Send to {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      junos_install_config:
        host="{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        file="/home/usr/resources/{{ inventory_hostname }}.set"
        overwrite=false
      delegate_to: localhost
```

(not tested)

Comment: Using this playbook returns the error

fatal: [vMX1] : FAILED! => ("ansible_facts": ("discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"), "changed": false, "msg": "missing required arguments: host")

Any advice?

Comment: No. I have no advice. It's not related to the question.